# StreamReader possible encoding issues

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, streamreader

I am having an issue while reading files in C# using a StreamReader. I have a file that is UTF-8 encoded. I am going to simplify it to one line for the example. The single line has a newline in it. I am reading with UTF-8 encoding, but once the string is read it does not seem to be treating the newline properly. Let me show the example

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("test1\ntest2" + " - " + "test1\ntest2".GetHashCode());
        Debug.WriteLine(line + " - " + line.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Here is the contents of the file

```
test1\ntest2
```

Here is the output from this code

```
test1
test2 - -61586127
test1\ntest2 - -228288099
```

In the line that is printed from the string literal it treats the \n as a newline when it prints it. When it prints the line read from the file it does not do this. You can also see that the hash code values are different.

Comment: It's not the same! In the file content the "\n" is a text, in c# code the "\n" is a newline because the character "\" is an escape character that tell to compiler that  the following char is "special". If you use "\t" you indicate the tab character

Comment: Is the "\n" actual contents of the file (e.g. ascii code 92 for '\', and ascii code 110 for 'n') or is the newline character 0x0A?

Comment: Are you having "\n" (backslash and letter n) actually written in your file, or it is a newline character, and you simply displayed it like that? It is compiler who turns special escape sequence like "\n" in string into newline character. When such a sequence is read from file, it is just "backslash and letter n", it won't be converted into newline automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of your file is wrong. In C# when using literal strings, characters with `\` prepended are treated like special characters (e.g. `\n` for NewLine, `\r` for carriage return, `\t` for tab, etc.). This is called escaping and `\` is the escape character. The sequence of `\` and some additional character results in one final character within a string.

While in your file's contents there are actual two characters (`\` and `n`), which are treated as actual characters not as a special one character. So in your file you actually need to put in NewLine character or replace `\n` with actual C#'s `\n` after reading from stream.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. I'm just so used to seeing \n as newline, I didn't think that it wouldn't be treated as an escape sequence when read in from the file.

Comment: Yes, this got me a few times too ;) Glad to help.